# How to make Shared Keys .ssh/authorized_keys and sudo work together?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, sudo

I've setup the .ssh/authorized_keys and am able to login with the new "user" using the pub/private key ... I have also added "user" to the sudoers list ... the problem I have now is when I try to execute a sudo command, something simple like:

```
$ sudo cd /root
```

it will prompt me for my password, which I enter, but it doesn't work (I am using the private key password I set)

Also, I've disabled the user's password using

```
$ passwd -l user
```

What am I missing?

Somewhere my initial remarks are being misunderstood ...

I am trying to harden my system ... the ultimate goal is to use pub/private keys to do logins versus simple password authentication. I've figured out how to set all that up via the authorized_keys file.

Additionally I will ultimately prevent server logins through the root account. But before I do that I need sudo to work for a second user (the user which I will be login into the system with all the time).

For this second user I want to prevent regular password logins and force only pub/private key logins, if I don't lock the user via" passwd -l user ... then if I don't use a key, I can still get into the server with a regular password.

But more **importantly** I need to get sudo to work with a pub/private key setup with a user whose had his/her password disabled.

---

**Edit:** OK, I think I've got it (the solution):

1) I've adjusted /etc/ssh/sshd_config and set `PasswordAuthentication no`
This will prevent ssh password logins (be sure to have a working public/private key setup prior to doing this

2) I've adjusted the sudoers list `visudo` and added

```
root      ALL=(ALL) ALL
dimas     ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

3) root is the only user account that will have a password, I am testing with two user accounts "dimas" and "sherry" which do not have a password set (passwords are blank, `passwd -d user`)

The above essentially prevents everyone from logging into the system with passwords (a public/private key must be setup).

Additionally users in the sudoers list have admin abilities. They can also `su` to different accounts. So basically "dimas" can `sudo su sherry`, however "dimas can NOT do `su sherry`. Similarly any user NOT in the sudoers list can NOT do `su user` or `sudo su user`.

**NOTE** The above works but is considered poor security. Any script that is able to access code as the "dimas" or "sherry" users will be able to execute sudo to gain root access. A bug in ssh that allows remote users to log in despite the settings, a remote code execution in something like Firefox, or any other flaw that allows unwanted code to run as the user will now be able to run as root. Sudo should always require a password or you may as well log in as root instead of some other user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ssh` and `sudo` have nothing to do with each other.  Setting up an `ssh` authentication method isn't going to do anything for `sudo`.  `sudo` isn't going to understand an `ssh` password.

`passwd -l` is intended to lock a user's account, so that he can no longer authenticate by password.  That's pretty much the opposite of what you want, which is letting the user authenticate without a password.

I think what you want is the `NOPASSWD` option in [your `sudoers` file](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudoers.man.html).

(PS, there's no reason to be running a `cd` command with `sudo`.  `cd` does not propagate to parent processes, so as soon as the `sudo` exits, you're back where you started.)

**Edit:**  You keep saying that you want to lock the account password and want sudo to understand public/private keys.  Sorry, sudo isn't going to use ssh keys.  It isn't ssh.  If you don't want users to be able to log in with their passwords, I think the answer is to [disable ssh password authentication](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring#Disable%20Password%20Authentication), not to lock the account.  Then you can retain a password for the users, which they can use to sudo after they log in via ssh authorized_keys.

Comment: ok, but does the fact that the user has no password via: passwd -l user ... cause the sudo command not to work?

Comment: @farinspace Yes, I understand the question better and have substantially expanded my remarks.  `passwd -l` removes the password in the sense that the account is LOCKED--that is, no password will work.  You want to turn off password authentication in sudo.

Comment: how is this logic: turning off the password in the sudoers file would still be secure, as the system is hardened via the pub/private key logins ... and again only admin would be able to add users to sudoers list

Comment: when using a private key is it typical to set a password for it, or is it secure enough to simply not have it set and bypass any password entry on server login

Comment: @coneslayer this reply is not 100% accurate. As you can see below, sudo can be configured to respect ssh authentication.

Answer (score 19):

What you want to do is possible but it will require some experience as you will have to compile a PAM module called **[pam-ssh-agent-auth](http://pamsshagentauth.sourceforge.net/)**.

The process is reasonably simple:

```
$ sudo aptitude install libssl-dev libpam0g-dev build-essential checkinstall
$ wget "http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/pamsshagentauth/pam_ssh_agent_auth/v0.9.3/pam_ssh_agent_auth-0.9.3.tar.bz2"
$ tar -xjvf pam_ssh_agent_auth-0.9.3.tar.bz2
$ cd pam_ssh_agent_auth-0.9.3

$ ./configure --libexecdir=/lib/security --with-mantype=man

$ make
$ sudo checkinstall
```

The edit the sudo configuration:

```
$ sudo visudo
```

Add the following:

```
Defaults env_keep += SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

Continue by changing the sudo PAM settings:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/pam.d/sudo
```

Add (just above the @include lines):

```
**auth [success=2 default=ignore] pam_ssh_agent_auth.so file=~/.ssh/authorized_keys**
@include common-auth
@include common-account
```

Comment: Another option can be found in [http://serverfault.com/questions/61796/easy-multi-level-authentication-for-sudo/303452#303452](http://serverfault.com/questions/61796/easy-multi-level-authentication-for-sudo/303452#303452)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: These instructions (particularly the `/etc/pam.d/sudo` instructions) are out of date for current Ubuntu versions.  I've provided updated instructions in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Andre de Miranda's answer provides a nice solution using [pam_ssh_agent_auth](http://pamsshagentauth.sf.net/), but parts are out of date.  Particularly the `/etc/pam.d/sudo` instructions when using many current Linux versions.

If you're running Ubuntu 12.04 precise, I've actually simplified the process by providing a pam_ssh_agent_auth build out of a ppa: [ppa:cpick/pam-ssh-agent-auth](https://launchpad.net/~cpick/+archive/pam-ssh-agent-auth).

You can install the package by running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cpick/pam-ssh-agent-auth
sudo apt-get install pam-ssh-agent-auth
```

After installation, if you'd like to use this PAM module with sudo you'll have to configure sudo's settings and PAM configuration, in Ubuntu 12.04 precise you can do that by creating the following two files:

/etc/sudoers.d/pam-ssh-agent-auth :

```
Defaults    env_keep+="SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
```

/etc/pam.d/sudo :

```
ent#%PAM-1.0

auth       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
auth       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
auth       sufficient pam_ssh_agent_auth.so file=/etc/security/authorized_keys
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

If you're using chef, the above process can be automated with my cookbook, found at either of the two following locations:
https://github.com/cpick/pam-ssh-agent-auth
http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/pam-ssh-agent-auth.

The cookbook's `files` directory contains the `/etc/pam.d/sudo` and `/etc/sudoers.d/pam-ssh-agent-auth` files described above that work with Ubuntu 12.04 precise and should be a helpful starting point when using other versions/distros.

Answer (score -1):

The only way I know to bypass entering a password is by disabling it in your `sudoers` file.

Something like this will give `root` and all members of `wheel` **full** access with no password:

```
root    ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL
```

This is absolutely **not advised**, however.  If you have a specific command for this server to execute, give them access to only that command.  Or better yet, find a different way to accomplish what you want to do which doesn't require punching a security hole.

Comment: i don't mind using the password, the problem it seems is after i disable the user password via: passwd -l user ... I can still login to the system via the pub/private key (private key has a secure password), when i do an sudo it asks for a password but this is not the password from the private key it seems, where is this password set if ive disabled it for the user (I would rather try to avoid maintaining a password on the ssystem and on the private key)

Comment: "where is this password set if ive disabled it for the user?"  Nowhere.  There is no password that you can type in that will work, because you have locked the account.

Comment: You would have to re-enable the account on the remote system and then set the password.  Either way, you should certainly maintain the password on both machines.  If for no other reason than local logins in case of a fault.